# Rodar ficheiro linguagem c em sricpt Python

Tags: python, c

Tenho um ficheiro de aquisição de dados analógicos convertidos em valores digitais (neste caso o valor de temperatura do sensor LM35) com o ADC Maxim 1203, gostaria agora de chamar o ficheiro num script Python para posterior envio desse valor para uma base de dados MySQL, é possível rodar um ficheiro com extensão .c da linguagem C num script de Python?

o código em C é este:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
#define MAX1202_3_lsb 0.001
#define MAX124_lsb 0.004

static const char *device = "/dev/spidev0.0";
static uint8_t mode = SPI_MODE_0;
static uint8_t bits = 8;
static uint32_t speed = 500000;
static uint16_t delay = 0;
static uint8_t deselect = 0;
static uint8_t input = 0;
static uint8_t verbose = 0;
static uint8_t unipolar = 8;
static uint8_t single = 4;
static uint8_t clock = 3;
static uint8_t newline = 1;
static uint8_t raw = 0;
static uint16_t bipolarconvert = 2047;
static float lsb = MAX1202_3_lsb;
static float fullscale = 0;
static uint8_t chip = 0 ; // chip type: 
//               0 for MAX1202 and MAX 1203
//               1 for MAX1204
static uint8_t inputtable[] = { 0, 64, 16, 80, 32, 96, 48, 112 };


static void pabort(const char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    abort();
}

static void vexit(const char *s)
{
    printf(s);
    if ( newline || verbose ) {
        printf("\n");
    }
    exit(1);
}

static void print_usage(const char *prog)
{
        printf("Usage: %s [-4Dscibkvnd]\n", prog);
        puts(
        "\n"
        " Maxim MAX1202 MAX1203 MAX1204 SPI adc utility\n"
        " Copyright (C) 2012  Alberto Panu\n"
        " http://www.panu.it/raspandmax/\n"
        "\n"
        " This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.\n"
        " This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it\n"
        " under certain conditions see GNU GPL v3\n"
        "\n"
        " Usage:\n"
        " -4 --max1204 select max1204 10 bit adc, default is max1202/3 12 bit\n"
        " -f --full full scale value, default are:\n"
        "      0 to 4.095 volt for unipolar mode\n"
        "      -2.048 to 2.047 volt for bipolar mode\n"
        " -D --device device to use (default /dev/spidev0.0)\n"
        " -s --speed SPI bus speed (Hz), default 500000\n"
        " -c --chipsel disable chipsel at read end, default don't disable\n"
        " -i --input chose input channel 0 to 7, default 0\n"
        " -b --bipolar set to bipolar mode, default unipolar, you need a -5V\n"
        "      power supply on pin 9!\n"
        " -k --clock set internal clock mode, default external\n"
        " -v --verbose print extra info usefoul for debug\n"
        " -r --raw raw mode ouput\n"
        " -n --newline suppress new line at non verbose output end\n"
        " -d --diff set to differential mode,\n"
        "      default is single ended, see table\n"
        "      for input channel selection:\n"
        "\n"
        "       ---------------\n"
        "      | Input l + | - |\n"
        "       ---------------\n"
        "      |   0   | 0 | 1 |\n"
        "       ---------------\n"
        "      |   1   | 2 | 3 |\n"
        "       ---------------\n"
        "      |   2   | 4 | 5 |\n" 
        "       ---------------\n"
        "      |   3   | 6 | 7 |\n"
        "       ---------------\n"
        "      |   4   | 1 | 0 |\n"
        "       ---------------\n"
        "      |   5   | 3 | 2 |\n"
        "       ---------------\n"
        "      |   6   | 5 | 4 |\n"
        "       ---------------\n"
        "      |   7   | 7 | 6 |\n"
        "       ---------------\n"
    );
    exit(1);
}

static void parse_opts(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (1) {
        static const struct option lopts[] = {
            { "input", 1, 0,'i' },
            { "full", 1, 0, 'f' },
            { "help", 0, 0, 'h' },
            { "speed", 1, 0, 's' },
            { "device", 1, 0, 'D' },
            { "verbose", 0, 0, 'v' },
            { "raw", 0, 0, 'r' },
            { "max1204", 0, 0, '4' },
            { "bipolar", 0, 0, 'b' },
            { "diff", 0, 0, 'd' },
            { "clock", 0, 0, 'k' },
            { "newline", 0, 0, 'n' },
            { NULL, 0, 0, 0 },
        };
        int c;

        c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "i:s:f:D:v4hbdknr", lopts, NULL);

        if (c == -1)
        break;

        switch (c) {

            case 'D':
            device = optarg;
            break;

            case 'i':
            input = atoi(optarg);
            break;

            case 'f':
            fullscale = atof(optarg);
            break;

            case 's':
            speed = atoi(optarg);
            break;

            case 'v':
            verbose = 1;
            break;

            case 'r':
            raw = 1;
            break;  

            case '4':
            chip = 1;
            break;

            case 'b':
            unipolar = 0;
            break;

            case 'd':
            single = 0;
            break;

            case 'k':
            clock = 2;
            break;

            case 'n':
            newline=0;
            break;

            default:
            print_usage(argv[0]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int ret = 0;

    parse_opts(argc, argv);

    if (speed > 2000000 || speed < 10000) {
        if ( verbose ) {
            vexit("Invalid speed, speed must be between 10000 and 2000000");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }

    if ( input > 7 || input < 0 ) {
        if ( verbose ) {
            vexit("Invalid input, input must be between 0 and 7");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    } 

    fd = open(device, O_RDWR);
        if (fd < 0) {
            if ( verbose ) {
                printf("%s\n", device);
                pabort("can't open device");
            } else {
                vexit("E");
            }
        }

    /*
    * spi mode
    */

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1 ) {
        close(fd);
        if ( verbose ) {
            pabort("can't set spi mode");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MODE, &mode);
    if (ret == -1) {
        close(fd);
        if ( verbose ) {
            pabort("can't get spi mode");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }

    /*
    * bits per word
    */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1) {
        close(fd);
        if ( verbose ) {
            pabort("can't set bits per word");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD, &bits);
    if (ret == -1) {
        close(fd);
        if ( verbose ) {
            pabort("can't get bits per word");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }

    /*
    * max speed hz
    */
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1) {
        close(fd);
        if ( verbose ) {
            pabort("can't set max speed hz");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }
    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_RD_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &speed);
    if (ret == -1) {
        close(fd);
        if ( verbose ) { 
            pabort("can't get max speed hz");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }

    if ( verbose ) {
        printf("device: %s\n", device);
        printf("spi mode: %d\n", mode);
        printf("bits per word: %d\n", bits);
        printf("max speed: %d Hz (%d KHz)\n", speed, speed/1000);
        printf("input port %d\n", input);   
    }

    if ( verbose ) {
        if ( chip ) {
            printf("chip MAX1204\n");
        } else {
            printf("chip MAX1202 or MAX1203\n");
        }
    }

    uint8_t transmitbyte = 0b10000000;

    transmitbyte |= inputtable[input];

    if ( unipolar ) {
        transmitbyte |= unipolar;
        if ( verbose ) {
            printf("unipolar mode\n");
        }
    } else {
        if ( verbose ) {
            printf("bipolar mode\n");
        }
    }

    if ( single ) {
        if (verbose ) {
            printf("single ended mode\n");
        }
        transmitbyte |= single;
    } else {
        if ( verbose ) {
            printf("diferential mode");
        }
    }

    transmitbyte |= clock;
    if ( verbose ) {
        if ( clock == 3 ) {
            printf("external clock mode\n");
        } else {
            printf("internal clock mode\n");
        }
    }

    if ( verbose ) {
        printf("transmit byte %d\n", transmitbyte);
    }

    uint8_t tx[] = {
        transmitbyte, 0, 0
    };

//  printf("Array tx dimension: %d\n", ARRAY_SIZE(tx));

    uint8_t rx[ARRAY_SIZE(tx)] = {0,};

    struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
        .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
        .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
        .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
        .delay_usecs = delay,
        .speed_hz = speed,
        .bits_per_word = bits,
        .cs_change = deselect,
    };

    ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
    if (ret < 1) {
        close(fd);
        if ( verbose ) {
            pabort("can't send spi message");   
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }

    close(fd);

    unsigned int first_byte = rx[ARRAY_SIZE(rx) - 3];
    unsigned int second_byte = rx[ARRAY_SIZE(rx) - 2];
    unsigned int third_byte = rx[ARRAY_SIZE(rx) - 1];

    if ( verbose ) {
        printf("First byte: %d\n", first_byte);
        printf("Second byte %d\n", second_byte);
        printf("Third byte %d\n", third_byte);
    }

    if ( first_byte && !chip ) {
        close(fd);
        if ( verbose ) {
            perror("Protocol error: the first byte is not 0!");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }

    if ( second_byte > 127 ) {
        close(fd);
        if ( verbose ) {
            perror("Protocol error: the first bit of the second byte must be 0!");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }

    unsigned int padding;

    padding = 7;

    if ( ( third_byte & padding ) != 0 ) {
        close(fd);
        if ( verbose ) {
            perror("Protocol error: the last three bit of the third byte must be 0");
        } else {
            vexit("E");
        }
    }

    signed long lettura;

    if ( chip ) {
        lettura = third_byte >> 5;
        lettura |= second_byte << 3;
        bipolarconvert = 511;
        lsb = MAX124_lsb;
    } else {
        lettura = third_byte >> 3; 
        lettura |= second_byte << 5;    
    }
    if ( !unipolar ) {
        if ( verbose ) {
                    printf("unipolar algorithm\n");
            }
        if ( lettura > bipolarconvert ) {
            lettura &= bipolarconvert;
            lettura -= bipolarconvert;
            lettura -= 1;
            if ( verbose ) {
                printf("Negative vaule");
                    }
        }   
    }


    float volt = lettura * lsb;
    if ( fullscale ) {
        volt = volt * fullscale / 4.096;
        if ( verbose ) {
                printf("Fullscale is %f\n", fullscale);
            }
    }
    if ( raw ) {
        if ( verbose ) {
            printf("Raw read: ");
        }
        printf("%d", lettura);
    } else {
        if ( verbose ) {
            printf("Analog read: ");
        }
        printf("%f", volt);
    }
    if ( newline || verbose ) {
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

e agora queria obter o valor do Analog Read no Python, esta é a minha dificuldade

tentei através do ctypes e não consigo obter o valor do Analog Read, o código é o seguinte:

```
from ctypes import*
adder = CDLL('./raspandmax.so')# segui o exemplo na explicação do CTypes na documentação do mesmo.
valor=adder.main()
print(valor)
```

Comment: Precisas de compilar o ficheiro com extensão .c. Podes rodar o executável que resulta da compilação anterior.

Comment: tenho o ficheiro compilado com extensão .c, agora queria chamar esse ficheiro num script Python e rodá-lo através do Python, isso é que não estou a conseguir programar

Answer (score 2):

O módulo ctypes do Python é uma forma de chamar funções em código nativo - incluindo funções escritas em C - a partir do Python.

Seu uso não é trivial, como costumam ser outras funcionalidades do Python (embora não seja muito mais complicado do que programar usando bibliotecas dinâmicas em C puro - exceto que se você vai usar uma biblioteca que não tem nenhum suporte específico para Python, tem que refazer as declarações de funções (os protótipos em C, normalmente nos arquivos ".h") em Python usando a as classes e funções do ctypes para isso.

Mas nesse caso, não só o seu programa em C (é diferente do que você escreveu:  você não "chama o ficheiro .c", você "executa código do programa compilado a partir do ficheiro .c", não só o código está feito para ser um programa completo stand-alone, com toda a funcionalidade direto na função `main`, como ele não retorna um valor, nem tem funções que retornam valores para quem chama - ele imprime os resultados na saída padrão.

Nesse caso faria pouco sentido você fazer manobras pra chamar esse códio diretamente com ctypes, já que os valores devolvidos pelas funções no programa não servem pra nada (o `main` deve retornar "0" em caso de sucesso).

O que você quer é capturar os dados que esse programa coloca na saída padrão, quando ele é executado como um processo independente.

Agora a boa notícia: isso é *bem* mais fácil de se fazer em Python do que chamar o código usando ctypes.

Tudo o que você precisa fazer é, estando o programa desejado no `PATH` do sistema - vamos dizer que se chama `read_sensors`:

```
import subprocess

sensor_data = subprocess.check_output("read_sensors").decode()
```

Pronto - a saída do programa está toda na variável "sensor_data" e você agora pode usar as funcionalidads do Python para manipular strings, como o método `split` e outros, para separar os dados desejados e utiliza-los a partir do Python.